# Check if value is in different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

so I am new to SQL and I have little experience with it. So please excuse if this is really basic but I can't seem to find it after googling...

so I have a table which contains a serialnumber field.
I have a single inputfield which contains comma seperated values with each one being a serialnumber. I just want to display the serialnumbers that are in that comma seperated string.

So I have a splitstring function that I can use which splits the string at the commas like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitString('sn1,sn2,sn3,sn4,sn5,sn6', ',')
```

this returns a table with each sn being a row.

So I would want something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tbl_serials AS sn
WHERE
    sn.serialnumber in dbo.SplitString('sn1,sn2,sn3,sn4,sn5,sn6', ',')
```

so this would display only the rows where the serialnumber is inside the string. But I don't know how to syntactily construct this.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method to do this is using `join`:

```
SELECT sn.*
FROM tbl_serials sn JOIN
     dbo.SplitString('sn1,sn2,sn3,sn4,sn5,sn6', ',') as ss(val)
     ON sn.serialnumber = ss.val;
```

With your route, you need a subquery:

```
SELECT sn.*
FROM tbl_serials sn JOIN
WHERE sn.serialnumber in (SELECT val
                          FROM dbo.SplitString('sn1,sn2,sn3,sn4,sn5,sn6', ',') as ss(val)
                         );
```

In both these cases, the `as ss(val)` assigns a table alias *and* a column alias to the value.  Some versions of `SplitString` might return more than one value (such as a position).  If you have such a version, then you need to include the extra return values as named columns.